# How can I slice values from data in amcharts Java based on a selected checkbox in a dropdown list?

Tags: java, amcharts5

I am trying to access data from an Java array (or some other concept I can't seem to find). I am familiar with Python but not so much with Java.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to select the ev[id] from a dataset, to execute a function based on the value.

- The console.log(ev); results:

  ```
  checked: false
  item:{id: 'activities', label: 'Display activities', form: 'checkbox', 
  value: '', checked: true}
  target: et {uid: 153, _settings: {…}, _privateSettings: {…}, 
  _settingEvents: {…}, _privateSettingEvents: {…}, …}
  type: 'changed'
  value: false
  [[Prototype]]: Object
  ```
- So I'm trying to access the Item.id and use it in an if statement. This is a function in AMcharts5:

  ```
    myDropdown.getPrivate("dropdown").events.on("changed", function (ev) {
        tooltiptoggle = !tooltiptoggle;
        console.log(ev);
        console.log(tooltiptoggle);
        if (ev['id'] == "emotion") {
            if (tooltiptoggle == true) {
                series.show();
                //yaxis.show();

            }
            if (tooltiptoggle == false) {
                series.hide();
                //  yaxis.hide();
            }
        }
    });
  ```
- Below is the full dropdown code; I am trying to add series and remove them based on the checkmarks.

  ```
  var myDropdown = am5stock.DropdownListControl.new(root, {
        stockChart: stockChart,
        name: "Options",
        fixedLabel: true,
        items: [{
            id: "emotion",
            label: "Display emotion result",
            form: "checkbox",
            value: "",
            checked: true
        },
        {
            id: "activities",
            label: "Display activities",
            form: "checkbox",
            value: "",
            checked: true
        }
        ]
    });


    myDropdown.getPrivate("dropdown").events.on("changed", function (ev) {
        tooltiptoggle = !tooltiptoggle;
        console.log(ev);
        console.log(tooltiptoggle);
        if (ev['id'] == "emotion") {
            if (tooltiptoggle == true) {
                series.show();
                //yaxis.show();

            }
            if (tooltiptoggle == false) {
                series.hide();
                //  yaxis.hide();
            }
        }

    });


    var toolbar = am5stock.StockToolbar.new(root, {
        container: document.getElementById("chartcontrols"),
        stockChart: stockChart,
        controls: [


            am5stock.DrawingControl.new(root, {
                stockChart: stockChart
            }),
            am5stock.ResetControl.new(root, {
                stockChart: stockChart
            }),
            myDropdown,
        ]
    })
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it; it turned out to be quite a simple syntax; have posted this here so others might be able to use it:

There is some other structure around this; but I did not want to copy the complete code.
Clearly it is not the most efficient way to do this but for this prototype chart it works fine!

```
    var myDropdown = am5stock.DropdownListControl.new(root, {
        stockChart: stockChart,
        name: "Select Chart",
        fixedLabel: true,
        items: [{
            id: "emotionprocess",
            label: "Smiley/ Activity",
            form: "checkbox",
            value: "",
            checked: false
        },
        {
            id: "category",
            label: "Categories",
            form: "checkbox",
            value: "",
            checked: false
        },
        {
            id: "totalhours",
            label: "Total Hours",
            form: "checkbox",
            value: "",
            checked: false
        },
        {
            id: "emotionresult",
            label: "Emotion of result",
            form: "checkbox",
            value: "",
            checked: false
        },
        ]
    });


    myDropdown.getPrivate("dropdown").events.on("changed", function (ev) {
        //     tooltiptoggle = !tooltiptoggle;
        console.log(ev);
        if (ev.item.id == 'category') {
            if (ev.checked == true) {
                series.show();
                yAxis.show();
            }
            else {
                series.hide();
                yAxis.hide();
            }
        }
        if (ev.item.id == 'totalhours') {
            if (ev.checked == true) {
                seriesTotalHours.show();
                yAxisTotalHours.show();
            }
            else {
                seriesTotalHours.hide();
                yAxisTotalHours.hide();
            }
        }
        if (ev.item.id == 'emotionresult') {
            if (ev.checked == true) {
                seriesavg.show();
                yAxisavg.show();
            }
            else {
                seriesavg.hide();
                yAxisavg.hide();
            }
        }
        if (ev.item.id == 'emotionprocess') {
            if (ev.checked == true) {
                seriessmiley5.show();
                seriessmiley6.show();
                seriessmiley7.show();;
                seriessmiley8.show();
                seriessmiley9.show();
                seriessmiley10.show();
                seriessmiley11.show();
                seriessmiley12.show();
                seriessmiley13.show();
                seriessmiley14.show();
                seriessmiley15.show();
                seriessmiley16.show();
                seriessmiley17.show();
            }
            else {
                seriessmiley5.hide();
                seriessmiley6.hide();
                seriessmiley7.hide();
                seriessmiley8.hide();
                seriessmiley9.hide();
                seriessmiley10.hide();
                seriessmiley11.hide();
                seriessmiley12.hide();
                seriessmiley13.hide();
                seriessmiley14.hide();
                seriessmiley15.hide();
                seriessmiley16.hide();
                seriessmiley17.hide();
            }
        }
```